# ts-check error: property does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a node code base and I want to migrate it to typescript. So the first thing I did was to add //@ts-check and fix the issues that typescript had. I could solve all the issues except for this one.

I need the client's ip address for the purpose of blacklisting clients that send too many redundant requests. So I use the middleware below to add the client's ip address to the request object.

```
app.use((request, _, next) => {
    const ip = request.get('x-real-ip')
    if (ip) {
        Object.defineProperties(request, { clientIP: { value: ip, writable: false } })
    } else {
        Object.defineProperties(request, { clientIP: { value:request.socket.remoteAddress, writable: false } })
    }
    next()
})
```

But when I want to access the clientIP property elsewhere, typescript gives the error below:

> Property 'clientIP' does not exist on type 'Request'.

What should I do to make this error go away?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to augment the `Request` interface in the `express-serve-static-core` module with the new property.  (According to the typings, the `express` module has a `Request` interface that extends the one in `express-serve-static-core`, but augmenting this one will not cover all uses.)  Put the following in a `.d.ts` file in your project:

```
declare module "dummy" {
    module "express-serve-static-core" {
        interface Request {
            clientIP: string;
        }
    }
}
```

The outer module declaration is needed to make the inner module declaration an "augmentation" instead of shadowing the original module, as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-338785578).  That trick is unfortunately not properly documented AFAIK.